# Can I read the font from one document, and embed that font in a brand new document, using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#-4.0, fonts, itext

In the below code (based on code previously provided by Chris Haas), I am reading the fonts from an existing document.  Using this method, I am able to re-use those font objects elsewhere in the existing document.  However, now I want to use this method to read the fonts in document "A", and embed them when I'm creating brand-new document "B".  Can this be done?

The BaseFont.CreateFont method here is taking a PRindirectReference as an argument, which keeps me from being able to specify "BaseFont.EMBEDDED" as an argument, as can be seen in overloaded versions of the method where the specific path to a font is known.

```
internal static HybridDictionary findAllFonts(PdfReader reader)
{

    HybridDictionary fd = new HybridDictionary();

    //Get the document's acroform dictionary
    PdfDictionary acroForm = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(reader.Catalog.Get(PdfName.ACROFORM));

    //Bail if there isn't one
    if (acroForm == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Get the resource dictionary
    var DR = acroForm.GetAsDict(PdfName.DR);

    //Get the font dictionary (required per spec)
    var fontDict = DR.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);

    foreach (var internalFontName in fontDict.Keys)
    {
        var internalFontDict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(fontDict.Get(internalFontName));
        var baseFontName = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(internalFontDict.Get(PdfName.BASEFONT));

        //Console.WriteLine(baseFontName.ToString().Substring(1, baseFontName.ToString().Length - 1));

        var iRef = (PRIndirectReference)fontDict.GetAsIndirectObject(internalFontName);
        if (iRef != null)
        {
            fd.Add(baseFontName.ToString().Substring(1, baseFontName.ToString().Length - 1).ToLower(),
                   BaseFont.CreateFont(iRef));
        }

    }

    return fd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't always be possible because usually fonts aren't embedded *entirely*. Instead you'll have subsets of the font. A glyph that is present in one subset may not be present in another subset.

Moreover, you'll face encoding problems: suppose that you have a document where Arial is used as a simple font for Greek glyphs. In that case, you'll have a maximum of 256 characters that can't be reused if you want to use Arial in another document to render a Russian text, or a text in Latin-1.

Even if you use Unicode, then you'll still have a problem, because there is not a single font that contains all Unicode characters. There are 1,114,112 code points in Unicode whereas a character identifier in a composite font can only be a number from 0 to 65,535...

You should really abandon the idea of reusing fonts that are present in existing documents to create new documents. On one side, it smells like you're trying to do something that is illegal (don't you have a license to use the actual fonts). On the other side your question sounds like: I have carrot soup, please tell me how to extract the original carrots from that soup so that I can reuse them for another purpose. You may have some results if you can still find large chunks of carrots in the soup, but in most cases, you'll fail.

For instance: if you have an elementary Type 1 font that is fully embedded, you should be able to copy all the essential elements of the font descriptor, but as soon as you're faced with the modern way of storing font subsets inside a PDF, you'll get stuck discovering that you're trying to do something that is simply impossible.

Comment: Good point.  I initially wanted to do this to create some re-usability of existing documents that were readily available, rather than storing the fonts on a server, and pulling them down, etc.  However, it looks like I'm not really saving myself much trouble that way.  I'll just store the fonts on the server and pull them down when needed.  Bruno, thank you for your time!